# show custom name in printerqueue with ghostscript

Tags: c#, ghostscript

the cod i wrote displayed down here is supposed to store the ghostscript arguments query in the variable and return the outputfilename var in the printerqueue under the file name. but for some reason once the code is executed the printerqueue is reached (it tells me its pauseed thats how i know) but the input in the queue flashes and then instantly dissapears.

i don't know if there is an error in my query or somewhere else, but i suspect the query to be faulty, i know to little of ghostscript to resolve this myself and this is kind of my last resort.

```
 var outputfilename = job.Configuration.PrintFileName.Name;
        var duplexSetting = SetDuplex(printJob);
        var colorSetting = SetColor(printJob);
        var copiesSetting = SetCopies(printJob);
        var gsArguments = string.Format($"-ghostscript \"{GhostScript.GetGsPrintExecutablePath()}\"" +
                                      $"{colorSetting}{duplexSetting}{copiesSetting} " +
                                      "-noquery -dPDFFitPage -printer \"" +
                                      $"{_printerRepository.Find(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == printJob.Printer)).PrinterName}\" \"" +
                                      $"{ printJob.SourceXml}\"" +
                                      $"-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -c \"mark / UserSettings <</ DocumentName({outputfilename}) >> (mswinpr2)finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice\"");

        var gsProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = GhostScript.GetGsPrintExecutablePath(),
            Arguments = gsArguments,
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

        var gsProcess = Process.Start(gsProcessInfo);
        gsProcess?.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Its impossible to tell form the code, because you don't give the actual values for any of the variables. Try printing out the entire string you use to execute Ghostscript, try that form the command line; if it works, then its probably some kind of escape problem, if it doesn't then you can post the command line here and I cna look at it.

Comment: You might also want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974159/ghostscript-doesnt-interpret-supplied-printer

Comment: ghostscript didnt let me past the whole commandline i pasted the section to get the file name starting from -DNOPAUSE. behind the code i already had.. here it is with filled variables : -ghostscript "C:\Development\AdvancedForms\src\AdvancedForms.Studio\bin\Debug\binaries\gsprint.exe" -colour -copies  -noquery -dPDFFitPage -printer "test printer" "C:\AdvancedForms\Runtime\Processes\f6259836-a74c-4f7a-920c-6f3a4a58c809\57affd3c-480f-41d9-85e9-0a1b9b0aa098.pdf"-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -c "mark / UserSettings <</ DocumentName(PDF output) >> (mswinpr2)finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice"

Comment: Your command line does not make sense, you have -ghostscript, you then pass gsprint.exe (apparently from an application named 'Advanced Forms', I have no idea what that is) You then pass in some options which make sense to Ghostscript, and some which make sense for gsprint, then what I guess is the input file, then some more Ghostscript options, and you don't appear to close the -c with a -f. You need to figure out if you are using Ghostscript or gsprint, put the options before the input file (after doesn't work) and clean up the options so you only use either GS or gsprint.

Comment: ahh okay i see, i have altered the commandline and told it to use gswin32.exe, now i have the full path to the temporaryfile in the printerqueue, instead of it flashing in and out and removing itself from the queue, this is the commandline: 'code' -ghostscript "C:\Development\AdvancedForms\src\AdvancedForms.Studio\bin\Debug\binaries\gswin32c.exe" -colour -copies  -noquery -dPDFFitPage -printer "test printer" "location of file and which is fully shown in queue" 'code' for now i've removed the line which shows the filename so it only show's the full pathe in the queue

Comment: i found a fix that worked for me, i added the variable containing the name set to display in the printerqueue at the end of the commandline between some quotes, in contrary of what the documentation states to use usersettings and documentname. i did it without and it works for some reason i can't figure out why but i sincerely thank you for your help @KenS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was fixed by displaying the commandline like so: `var gsArguments = string.Format("-ghostscript \"{0}\"{1}{2}{3} -noquery -dPDFFitPage -printer \"{4}\" \"{5}\" \"{6}\"",
               GhostScript.GetExecutablePath(),
               colorSetting,
               duplexSetting,
               copiesSetting,
               _printerRepository.Find(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == printJob.Printer)).PrinterName,
               printJob.SourceXml,
               outputfilename);`

all the variables represent specific settings and in contrary of what the documantion on ghostscript says that one should use /Usersettings and then /Documentname i just put the variable inline with the rest and it displays the name set to display in the printerqueue

if i misunterstood the documentation feel free to correct me, i'm posting this answer to help anyone with the same problem as i did in the future.